# Uninstall option missing from Windows 10 Start icon context menu for application installed with Inno Setup

Tags: windows-10, inno-setup, uninstallation

I created an install file with Inno Setup 5.5.9 that I then ran on a Windows 10 machine. My only problem has to do with uninstalling the program. I can use the Control Panel just fine to uninstall. But in the Start menu, when I right click on the shortcut that launches my program, there is no option in the context menu to *Uninstall*. Other programs do have this option.

Is this a Windows 10 thing that I can't get around?

Does the program need to be installed under Program Files or Program Files (x86)?

Or is there a change I can make to my Inno script to have the uninstall option show up?

I'm a standard user on the Windows 10 machine, and therefore installed the program without administrative privileges. Does that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only *"Windows apps"* (aka Universal Windows Platform [UWP] apps, Windows Store apps and Metro-style apps) have working *"Uninstall"* command.

---

Classic *"Desktop apps"*, like those installed with Inno Setup, do not. Their *Uninstall* command only opens *"Program and Features"* Control Panel. Check other major desktop apps, like *Microsoft Visual Studio* or *Google Chrome*. Their *"Uninstall"* command behaves the same. And they are definitely not packaged by Inno Setup.

You would have to [re-package your desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/source-code-overview) to turn it to *"Windows app"*, instead of using Inno Setup.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for your help Martin.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
In my case sometimes only the uninstall shortcut in windows start menu disappers.

I somehow fixed it. 
Just use in Icons-section the command to create this shortcut twice. Their names need to differ.

For example:

```
Name: "{group}\{#Uninstall_Name} {#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}";IconFilename: {app}\{#IconFileStartDesktop};

Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName} {#Uninstall_Name}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}" ;IconFilename: {app}\{#IconFileStartDesktop};
```

If the first uninstall-shorcut does not show up, the second one enter code here will to it.

Comment: works very nice! my uninstall shortcut is shown at the start menu group again. tested with win10 (v10.0.19042.1052)

Comment: This doesn't work anymore on Windows 11! 