# How to make uninstallation work by right clicking app icon from start menu

Tags: inno-setup, startmenu

For some reason INNO SETUP 6 installed applications cannot be easily uninstalled from Start menu.
There is nowadays an [option UNINSTALL appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550013/uninstall-option-missing-from-windows-10-start-icon-context-menu-for-application) for INNO installed icons under Windows 10/Start Menu when you right click the App icon.

So when I right click My App Icon created by Inno Setup 6, it has indeed an option Uninstall, but it goes to Control Panel/ Remove Apps section, instead of starting the uninst.exe right a way. Is there a fix for this available?

Comment: Nothing has changed. Maybe except that there's is now the *Uninstall* link (maybe it was there even before I've posted the linked answer, not sure). But as you know it only opens the control panel. It's not a fault of Inno Setup. Only Windows Store apps have working *Uninstall* command. Check Visual Studio or Chrome icons. They do not work either. I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48550013/850848#48555311).

Comment: As this is a Windows behavior, the "fix" would have to come from the Microsoft side (as Martin noted, this behavior has nothing to do with Inno Setup).

Comment: Ok thanks, I really appreciate how Inno setup works, its awesome, just interested to ask if there was any workaround to tweak that link by code somehow..

Comment: Imo, there's no workaround. It's not a link (shortcut). It's a built-in feature of the *Start* menu.